# Is it possible in VB.Net to pass a command to the Windows 10 Run Command?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, windows-10

I'm attempting to pass a command line argument to the Windows 10 Run Command via a VB.Net Application.
We have a support application that our staff use for numerous purposes, i'm hoping to be able to allow them to attempt to SMB into File Servers ( and prompt for Authentication ).

I attempted to also use a Process.Start for explorer.exe with the name of the File Share that they pass to it, but it doesn't prompt for authentication.

Anyone have any thoughts by chance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Process.Run".  There is `Process.Start`, and multiple of its overloads include a username and password (directly as arguments or as part of the `ProcessStartInfo` object).  It looks to me as though you will need to figure out for yourself whether to prompt, and it may not be trivial to figure that out---you can get an exit code, but that depends on the process setting that correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean Process.Start not Process.Run.
What i'm running into on this is that when I attempt to run explorer.exe with a directory of \\computername\c$ unless I have already authenticated to it for the day it will not function and will instead open the documents folder.  It does not prompt for authentication.  I was hoping that there would be a way to launch the Windows Run Command with a parameter passed to it, but I have not been able to find much for this.
I found that you can call explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}, but can't seem to pass parameters.

Comment: Does it help if you provide authentication (username/password) to `Process.Start` proactively?

Comment: You might want to check on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). There are already some related questions ([google](https://www.google.com/search?q=explorer+open+share+with+credentials) and check the first results). Basically, what you could do is, to run `net use ...` with relevant credentials first, then open explorer to access the share (or drive you mapped it to). `net use` could also be done in code, if you don't want to run another external command, but for testing/prototyping I wouldn't bother.